# Find Element Using XPath

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, xpath

I am trying to click on "create account" for gmail using xpath.

```
<span id="link-signup">
<a href="https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?service=mail&amp;continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&amp;ltmpl=default">
  Create account
  </a>
  </span>
```

My code in python:

```
elem=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@span='link-signup']").click()
```

I'm not sure what the error is. I know how to click the link by id but I want to learn how to do it by the xpath for future purposes.

Comment: try to search for "Create account" like explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18655765/xpath-find-html-element-by-plain-text

Comment: did you try './/span[@id="link-signup"]' ?

Comment: searching for the a tag containing "Create account" should work like this: `//a[contains(text(),'Create account')]`

Comment: Thank you @Sword your suggestion worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using :
the `'.//'` selects a child node with the tag `span` and the square brackets are used to select it by attribute i.e `id`.

```
elem=driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@id="link-signup"]').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

try it with `following-sibling`:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@id='link-signup']/following-sibling::a").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of example XPaths to retrieve the 'Create account' link:

```
//Returns an a element with the exact text 'Create account'
//a[.='Create account']

//Returns an 'a' element that is the child of a span element with the id 'link-signup'
//span[@id='link-signup']/a
```

The XPath given in your question `//*[@span='link-signup']` is not a valid XPath because the `@span='link-signup'` predicate is trying to find an element which has a span *attribute* equal to *'link-signup'*, whereas the HTML given in your question has a `span` element with an *id* attribute equal to *'link-signup'*.

Additionally, the XPath given in your question does not attempt to return the `a` element that contains the link you want to click.