# XPath select deepest element of unknown type

Tags: html, xpath

I have an HTML table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <div class="header">test</div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="header">
            <div class="subheader">
                <span>test2</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to know how to select deepest element in `<td>` without needing to use multiple xpath queries.

```
//table/tr/td/*[last()]/text()
```

So the query result would be:

> Text='test' Text='test2'

Comment: Hello Elvinai, see ancestor-or-self

Comment: You can simply use  `//table/tr/td//text()` there is no need in `last()`

Comment: Thank you,but with this solution I need to know which index to select, for example, I get: 'test', '', '', test2, '',''

Comment: @3lvinaz , I see no `","` nodes on provided HTML sample

Comment: For true deepest node selection in XPath, see [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11135620/290085)

Comment: If the above link doesn't help, please [edit] your question and add more elements to your example that you wish ***not*** to be selected by your sought XPath. As it stands, your example fails to illustrate what you mean by "deepest". Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for that, I will try my best next time :). That question fits my requirements as well... I have so much to choose from now :D

Comment: If *deepest* and *last* both fit your requirements, it's likely that your requirements are ill-stated.  *Deepest* pertains to a count along the ancestor-descendant direction; *last* refers to an ordering of nodes in a document sequence direction.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Andersson I managed to select deepest element in `<td>`.

Query looks like this:

```
//table/tr/td/descendant::*[last()]
```

And query result is:

> `Element='<div class="header">test</div>' Element='<span>test2</span>'`

Which node values are:

> Element='test' Element='test2'

Everyone thank you so much for the effort and sorry for accepting answer which wasn't actually correct one.

Comment: You're right in this point, but in my scenario this query fits perfectly, because we have only one deepest element, but maybe in the future there will be more than one.

Comment: Then perhaps you misunderstand what *deepest* means.  @PaulCrovella has a very valid point.  Note that your sample is too simple to differentiate *deepest* from *last*.