# How to get all the deepest elements of a given type?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>cell 1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><b>cell 2</b></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <table>
            <tr>
               <td><span>cell 3</span></td>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Can I use XPath to get `<td>cell 1</td>`, `<td><b>cell 2</b></td>` and `<td><span>cell 3</span></td>`, **but not** the outer `<td><table>...` (because it has a nested `td` inside)?

Note the inner `table` here is just an example. I want the deepest `td` elements, meaning they cannot have another `td` as a descendant.

XPath 1.0 is preferred so I can use `lxml`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135620/how-to-get-the-most-deeply-nested-element-nodes-using-xpath-implementation-wit) is a similar question, but here I know I want `td` elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`//td` will return every `td` in the document.

`//td[not(.//td)]` will return every `td` that does not contain (as one of its descendants) a `td` element.

Comment: You probably meant `//`.

Comment: @sourcream in the expression `//td[not(.//td)]` the path `.//td` in the predicate starts with a `.` which refers to the "context node" which in this case is a `td` identified by the `//td` at the start of the path. Equally, I could have written `//td[not(descendant::td)]` and probably that would have been clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Since a `td` must be a part of a `table` this  XPath should be the fastest.

```
//td[not(descendant::table)]
```

Comment: `table` is just an example of a nested element. I want the deepest `td`, it doesn't matter what is inside. I will clarify the question.

Comment: I adjusted the answer